# Where does the authenticated user go?

Tags: java, authentication, web-applications, httprequest

If I want to call `request.isUserInRole("SOME_ROLE")` this means that the request knows about the user making it (assuming the user is authenticated) , my question is : after the user is authenticated where does his information go so that the request knows about it later ? I know that in case of enterprise application , it's stored in a `java.security.Principal` object, is this the same in a simple web application ?

can I use `request.isUserInRole("SOME_ROLE")` while using FORM based authentication `<auth-method>FORM</auth-method>`  .... will the authenticated user be reflected to the request automatically?

Answer (score 0):

Usually  in simple webapps, the logged in user information is put into http session.

Comment: this is the default behavior implemented by the container when using BASIC authentication, or what we put in our code when implementing auth2 ?